# Laravel's latest version for production

Tags: laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and impressed by its popularity, performance, developer's adaption and so many other things which has put [Laravel](http://www.sitepoint.com/best-php-framework-2015-sitepoint-survey-results/) on top of stack than other frameworks.

I have heard about new latest version 5.0 and 5.1 but could not found exact version for production (or whether it is still 4.x).

1. I would like to know which is the latest version of Laravel to start with?
2. How to manage database level changes (migration in Laravel - need to know more)?
3. What if new bug fixes updated by Laravel (Taylor Otwell) and how to update them on development or production environment?

Please help me out for this.

Comment: 1. 5.1 is just fine - it is marked as stable on [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/laravel); 2. Yep, migrations should cover everything; 3. You should use Composer to manage your PHP deps, that will fetch you a fresh version every time it is available and you run composer update (of course, it should fall under constraints specified in composer.json)

Comment: 5.1 is good, it has 2 yrs LTS (long term support), and 3 yrs for security bugs. Here is the link: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/releases#support-policy